# How to create a user authentication without SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, user-input

I have a project running in vb.net. It's currently a very small project, so I have used XML serialization as the main way of storing information. I.e. creating a xml file in the .exe folder. and saving/reading from there.

**Problem:** Since the project is small, I have no SQL database setup and I would like to           keep it that way. But I do want to create a user/password for access to the program.

**What I have tried:** I have tried using XML serialization, but hiding the xml file. Once I hide it, I'm unable to access the file (saying I have no permissions).

What's a good way to have the same utility without using SQL and not giving away security?

Comment: if the Exe will be installed to `Program Files` as is normal, your app likely will not have permission to read/write there.  That is what `Users\AppData` is for.  It will seem to work in the IDE because AppPath is where you store your VS projects, like `MyDocuments`.  Since you decided on XML stuff will be readable.  You could encrypt the names(s)/passwords(s), or use Binary Serialization (or both)

Comment: User's will very likely be able to discover your password.

Comment: True. I don't really need too much security, but I wanted to see what is considered the best option out there without SQL.

Comment: Then why hide it? Like @Plutonix suggested just put the file there.

Comment: where you store data files has little to do with security. "hiding" files from a user on his **own system** is problematic: what happens if they want to move their data to a new drive/system? Securing login info is something else entirely and having a DB doesnt always eliminate that.

Comment: So from what I'm reading here, the only options are basically encryption to maybe a local pattern I chose or possibly even making it one of those strings in the app data. There's no other common method of creating authentication that I'm missing?

Comment: Any security that you put on the user's computer (solely) could be beaten/broken with enough determination. The reason is that the key for decrypting your security would already be on that machine (built into your program, which can be decompiled). So, you really need to determine if you want your security to be real security, in which case, you need some kind of authentication server, or if you want reasonably decent security, in which case, a local hash of the login/password should be fine. Pick one.

Comment: Are we just talking about one user/password here?

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the file is pointless.  You should simply hash the passwords and then store the data just as you do for any other data.  That's exactly what you'd do if you were using a database too.  When a user registers, you hash the password they provide and store the result.  Anyone can then view the data without breaching security because they cannot get the original value from the hash.  When a user logs in, you hash the password they provide and compare that to the value in the database and, if they match, the user is authenticated.

You should do some reading on hashing in general and also consider adding a salt for extra security, although that may not be worthwhile in this case.